# UIWebView: Cancel opening a link when "touch up" is outside of the link?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with links in the text which open Safari if pressed.

If a user touches a link, it darkens...but if he wants to cancel pressing the link by moving his finger away first, it stays dark, and releasing the finger anywhere opens the link.

Is there some way to enable the user to "cancel" his "click" by moving away his finger - along the lines of the behavior of a "touch up inside" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of doing exactly what you asked using the public SDK.
The best answer I can think of is to track touch began and touch ended events for the UIWebView itself.
Then, add a `UIWebviewDelegate`, and to this delegate's interface, add a boolean `bLastTouchDidWander` (name is purely for example)

On a touch Down, you set `bLastTouchDidWander` to false.

On a touch UP, you measure how far the touch moved. If it moved more than a set amount, consider this a "touch up outside", and set `bLasTTouchDidWander` to true.

Then ,for the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` message of the `UIWebViewDelegate`, if `bLastTouchDidWander` is true, don't follow the link.

Comment: interesting idea, i'll have to try it.

Comment: haven't tried it yet, so can't confirm whether it works, but am accepting since you're the only one who responded. :) Thanks!